# PostgreSQL: how to query statistics of a step in pg_agent?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

PgAdmin shows statistics of each run of a step of pg_agent (job). The list details the run ID, status, result, start & end & duration.
The following is how it looks:

[image]

How to get it by query command ?

Comment: The tables the extension creates, can be seen [here](https://github.com/postgres/pgagent/blob/master/sql/pgagent.sql)

Answer (score 2):

pg_agent create a catalog (like a schema) 'pgagent' for each database,
you can query the different log table as follow:

- pgagent.pga_joblog
- pgagent.pga_jobsteplog

To get log of all step runs :

```
SELECT * FROM pgagent.pga_jobsteplog
```

Best regards,
Tim